Issue with ntpd Capabilities When droproot is False
I am experiencing an issue with ntpd on my system after upgrading it from 4.2.8p10 to 4.2.8p17.
I have configured ntpd to run with have_caps enabled, but droproot is set to false.
This configuration seems to cause ntpd to retain certain capabilities, which is not the desired behavior.
Is there a patch available for Bug 1433, or is there a recommended workaround for this situation?
Any assistance or guidance on this matter would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you,
Thiru.
